# How to allow yawcam (ip-camera software) through windows firewall

Tags: firewall, windows-firewall, ip-camera

I'm trying to set up [yawcam (ip camera software)](http://yawcam.com/) to watch my 3D printer from outside of my network. I did the necessary port-forwarding, disabled my firewall, and successfully connected to the camera from outside of my network. The problem is that, after re-enabling my firewall, the connection is blocked (or not specifically allowed). I have tried allowing the program through the firewall by the program path, as well as by port and neither has worked. I know for a fact that the issue is with my firewall, I just can't find what. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So turns out I had to allow javaw (found in C:\program files (x86)\java\jre1.8.0_60\bin\javaw.exe) through the firewall, not the specific program.